# Using HTML5's VIDEO tag in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I am using the video tag in asp.net as such:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/fort.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Training.aspx.cs" Inherits="Training" %>


    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">


    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
     <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />   
    </video>     


   </asp:Content>
```

When I run the program the video comes up put not clickable. It works fine in a html file, just not in a .aspx file.

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong? The rendered HTML should be the same being served up from ASP.NET, as your code for the video has no server controls or interaction.

Comment: What doctype are you using in your masterpage?